# Maui App Sqllite not working in Android but works in Windows

Tags: android, sqlite

The below App works in Windows but not in Android , please suggest, I think its failing when interfacing with Sqlite.

https://github.com/KalyanAllam/RateApp

I installed the below nuget packages

[image]